# How do you SAVE user rating in rating bar?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

Hello all :) I have a rating bar and it works but the rating doesn't save when the user leaves the page. How do you save the user rating?

**Here's the code**

```
RatingBar ratingBar;
TextView ratingText;
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.list_item_activity_1);       
       ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
       ((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1)).setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);    
       wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
boolean fromTouch) {    
       final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
       editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
       editor.putInt("numStars", numStars);
       editor.commit();  
       int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 0);
       ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + ratings.toString());
}
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: You can use sharedpreferences for that,..Check my answer..

Comment: Save the ratings in sharedpreference before leaving the app and retrieve the ratings from sharedpreference and set it in the ratings bar when you come back to the application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SharedPreferences** for that..

Save the ratings in `SharedPreferences` before leaving the app and retrieve the ratings from `SharedPreferences` and set it in the ratings bar when you come back to the application..

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1,wmbPreference2;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

//wmbPreference for Shared Prefs that lasts forever
wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  

//installsp for Shared Prefs that lasts only just once each time program is running
wmbPreference2 =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MYKEY",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**To save values**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putString("MYKEY", "12345");
editor.commit();
```

You can **retrieve the values** like

```
String Phonenumber = wmbPreference1.getString("MYKEY", "");
```

where **MYKEY** is the **keyname** by which you can identify the value..

---

**EDIT**

---

Change your code like this

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference1;    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_item_activity_1);  
ratingText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
((RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1))
.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);  
wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);      
}

@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
boolean fromTouch) {
final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
editor.putInt("numStars", numStars);
editor.commit();
```

And when you come back do this,ie when you want to retrieve the ratings

```
int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 0);
ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + String.valueOf(ratings));
```

Here `ratings` will hold the ratings which was set earlier..

Comment: I tried to implement the code Lal but it still wouldn't save, I probably made a mistake. I added the rating bar xml if it helps at all

Comment: It wont save as it is..You do one thing..Get the number of ratings from the rating bar and save that to sharedpreference..Then retrieve the rating from sharedpreference and set it on the rating bar

Comment: Hey Lal, first I want to thank you for all your help, I've never implemented a rating bar or shared preferences before, so thanks for your patience. I implemented the code and it seems to have no errors except one which is probably my fault again. on getInt there is an error saying "The method getInt(String, int) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)" I have updated the code above to show how I tried to implement it which may be wrong...

Comment: Change `String ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", "");` to `int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 0);`

Comment: So change `ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + ratings);` as `ratingText.setText(rating + "/" + ratings.toString());`

Comment: I changed the code and there are no errors now but it does not save the rating, upon restart in emulator I get an error message saying  Starting activity com.example.deliciousglutenfreerecipes.Splash on device emulator-5554
[2014-05-18 14:33:45 - DeliciousGlutenFreeRecipes] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.deliciousglutenfreerecipes.Splash }
[2014-05-18 14:33:45 - DeliciousGlutenFreeRecipes] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front. Thanks again..

Comment: SAhould I be putting this code in main_activity because right now it's in a list_item_activity_1 class, not main activity, it's for a specific page. I call the class from main activity and it runs an xml page..

Comment: Changed rating text, it says Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int