# Trying to save user selected rating into shared preferences

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

my ratings are not being saved. withing each conditional statement i call the method onRatingChange(). so once i give the item a rating..i hit the back button and re click on the previous item but the rating is set back to the default.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class infoFragment extends Fragment implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener {

    TextView degrees;
    ImageView image;
    String stringtext;
    String [] hold;
    RatingBar rating;
    SharedPreferences wmbPreference1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_layout, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rating = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        rating.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
        wmbPreference1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        degrees =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
```

this method is used to save the preferences and/or retrieve preferences
I used this  as a reference: [How do you SAVE user rating in rating bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719641/how-do-you-save-user-rating-in-rating-bar)

```
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                            boolean fromTouch) {
        //if nothing was saved do this 
       if(ratingBar==null) {
           final int numStars = ratingBar.getNumStars();
           editor = wmbPreference1.edit();
           editor.putInt("numStars", numStars);
           editor.commit();
           int ratings = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars", 2);
       }
        else
          // int number = wmbPreference1.getInt("numStars",0); trying to  retreive saved data
    }
    public void setText(final String string) {
       Character[] hold;
        if(string == "apple"){
            String[] word = { " A \n", "B\n" };

            degrees.setText(Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));;
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.APPLE);
             onRatingChanged(rating,0,true);//calling method to save data
    }
      if(string == "orange"){
            String[] word = { " AA\n", "AB\n" };
            degrees.setText(Arrays.toString(word).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));;
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
             onRatingChanged(rating,0,true);//calling method to save data
        }
    }

    public void sentText(){
        new MyTask().execute();

    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Bundle b = getArguments();
            stringtext = b.getString("text");
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){setText(stringtext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `onRatingChanged`, the `RatingBar` object is not always null. And the second parameter represents what the current number about starts. The `getNumStarts()` returns `maxStarts` for this `ratingBar`.

Comment: Thanks   -1 how can i determine the initial time from the user selected times. use 0 instead of null?  -2 so if i cant use getNumStars what can i use to get the numbers the user has selected?   -3 what do you mean "current number about starts?

Comment: @ A.simple  did you look at the reference i supplied, it worked for there program, and was selected as the right answer, not sure why it gives me an inssue

Comment: -1 you can initial the ratingBar in 0nCreateView method.-2 in the method onRatingChanged,the first parameter is represent the user is operating RatingBar and it's you defined in the method onCreateView. -3.you can get the numbers the user has selected by the second parameter. invoke the method which getNumStarts  will be rerurn the total starts in this RatingBar

Comment: i went in a different direction but figured it out...you made me think of something else that helped me figure it out